# Why are XAML namespaces URIs and what are they for?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xml-namespaces, wpf-4.0

I am skeptical regarding the XML namespaces. I don't know why we need these namespaces in all XAML applications.

```
xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation
xmlns:x=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml
```

I understand the concept of namespaces as in System.Text, System.LINQ, etc. We use that in our classes because we have class libraries that sit on the same computer.

Questions:

1. It represents some URI. So WPF is standalone application. If the user of the app is not connected to Internet, whats the significance of it? First of all why do we need this?
2. What's the difference between the first and second line? What does `xmlns:x` represent?
3. Also, I see this error upon trying to access that URI

   > An error occurred while processing your request

   What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URLs mentioned in the definitions of the namespaces have nothing to do with actual internet-connection or real existing URLs; this is just a convention used so the namespaces can be properly distinguished.

A XAML-namespace is just like a namespace in C++ or C#/VB.NET, it serves the purpose of logically grouping classes and other items.

In WPF/XAML you have a namespace `xmlns=http://...` which is the namespace for the controls WPF offers you by default. `xmlns:x` is a namespace to provide some special values like `x:Null` to represent a `null`-value.
You can define your own controls and name them `TextBox`, too, but you should create an own namespace for these in order to not interfer with the global namespace.

There is a nice article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms747086.aspx) about this topic.

Comment: Thank you Bash. However I really dont understand why MS has to complex things in XAML and something different in C# of .NET. Because ideally in C# or .NET we use "System." format for built in namespaces. Likewise, this two URLs are also a built in type you say. And the "Very purpose of .NET is to ease the developer from having to remember many classes like MFC blah blah but to use a single BASE CLASS LIBRARY". I wonder why again they confuse developers with some other paradigm in xaml. Its not encouraging certainly.

Comment: @Divine This has barely anything to do with .NET itself, but rather with XML. XAML is based on XML and so obeys the rules of it.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on this, it has to do more with xml than .NET. Well, I take it the way it is :) Thanks Bash, your post helps me and I will go through that MSDN article too :) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It's the way those namespaces were named. That's all. You should not treat them as uri.
As for xmlns vs xmlns:x - the first one is the default namespace, which contains wpf controls, the second one is namespace whcih contains some additional declarations (x:Type, x:Name, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I think the information provided in the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15271211/3195477) is not totally correct. The url which you see is not a namespace but a collection of namespaces grouped into one. Below are some of the namespaces from .net which are mapped by default namespace (url)

System.Windows, System.Windows.Automation, System.Windows.Controls, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives, System.Windows.Data, System.Windows.Documents